# Extra data in JSON results and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have an entity data model with two tables that are related (`Projects` and `ProjectTasks`). The `ProjectTasks` table has a foreign key of the `ProjectID` in it, so the entity data model associates the two tables.

I am attempting to get all tasks with the project ID of "X" (the X in this is unimportant) and return them in JSON. If the entity model has just the `ProjectTasks` table, it produces pretty normal results, like this one for project ID 15745:

```
[{
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1000,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 1","FirstTask":true,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-09T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43284},{
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 2","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43285},{
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1250,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 3","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":10,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-21T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-19T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43286},{
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":2300,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 4":false,"PlannedDuration":0,"Team_ID":3,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":null,"AssignedUser_ID":"","Completed_By":"","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43287},{
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":4554,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 5","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-10T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-28T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-29T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43288},{
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":6200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 6","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43289}
]
```

The results go bonkers if I include the `Project` table in the entity data model however:

```
[
"Projects":
"ProjectTasks":[
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 2","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43285},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1250,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 3","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":10,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-21T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-19T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43286},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":2300,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 4","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":0,"Team_ID":3,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":null,"AssignedUser_ID":"","Completed_By":"","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43287},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":4554,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 5","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-10T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-28T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-29T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43288},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":6200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 6","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43289}],"Project_ID":15745,"ProjectType_ID":2,"ServiceStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","EmployerRef":"Sample Reference","Employer_ID":999999,"DocFolder":"","SalesStatus_ID":6,"SalesContact":"","ClientType_ID":2,"ChannelPartner_ID":4,"SelfInsuredMed":-1,"ProjectedRevenue":0,"NotificationDate":"2017-05-04T00:00:00","PHNumber":0,"Region_ID":0,"Segment_ID":0,"CCI_Required":0,"SSN_ID":1,"PlanYearStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","CardStatus_ID":1,"Cardcount":0,"PRIN":"","ConnectedClaims":0,"HSAFundingModel_ID":0,"CarryOverStatus_ID":2,"FundingDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","TermDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ProjectStatus_ID":2,"AccountMgr_ID":"A123456","SSO":0,"CustomWeb":0,"CustomWebURL":"","FSATakeover":0,"TOFileExpectedDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","NCC":-1,"Executed_Contract":null,"Performance_Guarantee":null,"Enrollment_Entered":null},"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1000,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 1","FirstTask":true,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-09T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43284},
"Projects":
"ProjectTasks":[
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1000,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 1","FirstTask":true,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-09T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43284},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1250,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 3","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":10,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-21T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-19T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43286},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":2300,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 4","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":0,"Team_ID":3,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":null,"AssignedUser_ID":"","Completed_By":"","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43287},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":4554,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 5","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-10T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-28T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-29T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43288},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":6200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 6","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43289}],"Project_ID":15745,"ProjectType_ID":2,"ServiceStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","EmployerRef":"Sample Reference","Employer_ID":999999,"DocFolder":"","SalesStatus_ID":6,"SalesContact":"","ClientType_ID":2,"ChannelPartner_ID":4,"SelfInsuredMed":-1,"ProjectedRevenue":0,"NotificationDate":"2017-05-04T00:00:00","PHNumber":0,"Region_ID":0,"Segment_ID":0,"CCI_Required":0,"SSN_ID":1,"PlanYearStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","CardStatus_ID":1,"Cardcount":0,"PRIN":"","ConnectedClaims":0,"HSAFundingModel_ID":0,"CarryOverStatus_ID":2,"FundingDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","TermDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ProjectStatus_ID":2,"AccountMgr_ID":"A123456","SSO":0,"CustomWeb":0,"CustomWebURL":"","FSATakeover":0,"TOFileExpectedDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","NCC":-1,"Executed_Contract":null,"Performance_Guarantee":null,"Enrollment_Entered":null},"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 2","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43285},
"Projects":
"ProjectTasks":[
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1000,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 1","FirstTask":true,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-09T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43284},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 2","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43285},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":2300,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 4","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":0,"Team_ID":3,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":null,"AssignedUser_ID":"","Completed_By":"","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43287},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":4554,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 5","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-10T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-28T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-29T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43288},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":6200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 6","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43289}],"Project_ID":15745,"ProjectType_ID":2,"ServiceStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","EmployerRef":"Sample Reference","Employer_ID":999999,"DocFolder":"","SalesStatus_ID":6,"SalesContact":"","ClientType_ID":2,"ChannelPartner_ID":4,"SelfInsuredMed":-1,"ProjectedRevenue":0,"NotificationDate":"2017-05-04T00:00:00","PHNumber":0,"Region_ID":0,"Segment_ID":0,"CCI_Required":0,"SSN_ID":1,"PlanYearStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","CardStatus_ID":1,"Cardcount":0,"PRIN":"","ConnectedClaims":0,"HSAFundingModel_ID":0,"CarryOverStatus_ID":2,"FundingDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","TermDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ProjectStatus_ID":2,"AccountMgr_ID":"A123456","SSO":0,"CustomWeb":0,"CustomWebURL":"","FSATakeover":0,"TOFileExpectedDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","NCC":-1,"Executed_Contract":null,"Performance_Guarantee":null,"Enrollment_Entered":null},"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1250,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 3","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":10,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-21T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-19T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43286},
"Projects":
"ProjectTasks":[
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1000,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 1","FirstTask":true,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-09T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43284},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 2","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43285},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1250,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 3","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":10,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-21T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-19T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43286},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":4554,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 5","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-10T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-28T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-29T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43288},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":6200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 6","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43289}],"Project_ID":15745,"ProjectType_ID":2,"ServiceStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","EmployerRef":"Sample Reference","Employer_ID":999999,"DocFolder":"","SalesStatus_ID":6,"SalesContact":"","ClientType_ID":2,"ChannelPartner_ID":4,"SelfInsuredMed":-1,"ProjectedRevenue":0,"NotificationDate":"2017-05-04T00:00:00","PHNumber":0,"Region_ID":0,"Segment_ID":0,"CCI_Required":0,"SSN_ID":1,"PlanYearStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","CardStatus_ID":1,"Cardcount":0,"PRIN":"","ConnectedClaims":0,"HSAFundingModel_ID":0,"CarryOverStatus_ID":2,"FundingDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","TermDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ProjectStatus_ID":2,"AccountMgr_ID":"A123456","SSO":0,"CustomWeb":0,"CustomWebURL":"","FSATakeover":0,"TOFileExpectedDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","NCC":-1,"Executed_Contract":null,"Performance_Guarantee":null,"Enrollment_Entered":null},"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":2300,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 4","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":0,"Team_ID":3,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":null,"AssignedUser_ID":"","Completed_By":"","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43287},
"Projects":
"ProjectTasks":[
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1000,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 1","FirstTask":true,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-09T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43284},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 2","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43285},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1250,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 3","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":10,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-21T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-19T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43286},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":2300,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 4","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":0,"Team_ID":3,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":null,"AssignedUser_ID":"","Completed_By":"","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43287},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":6200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 6","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43289}],"Project_ID":15745,"ProjectType_ID":2,"ServiceStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","EmployerRef":"Sample Reference","Employer_ID":999999,"DocFolder":"","SalesStatus_ID":6,"SalesContact":"","ClientType_ID":2,"ChannelPartner_ID":4,"SelfInsuredMed":-1,"ProjectedRevenue":0,"NotificationDate":"2017-05-04T00:00:00","PHNumber":0,"Region_ID":0,"Segment_ID":0,"CCI_Required":0,"SSN_ID":1,"PlanYearStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","CardStatus_ID":1,"Cardcount":0,"PRIN":"","ConnectedClaims":0,"HSAFundingModel_ID":0,"CarryOverStatus_ID":2,"FundingDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","TermDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ProjectStatus_ID":2,"AccountMgr_ID":"A123456","SSO":0,"CustomWeb":0,"CustomWebURL":"","FSATakeover":0,"TOFileExpectedDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","NCC":-1,"Executed_Contract":null,"Performance_Guarantee":null,"Enrollment_Entered":null},"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":4554,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 5","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-10T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-28T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-29T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43288},
"Projects":
"ProjectTasks":[
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1000,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 1","FirstTask":true,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-09T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43284},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 2","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-06T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-07T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-06-03T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43285},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":1250,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 3","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":10,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-21T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-06-05T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-06-19T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"U123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43286},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":2300,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 4","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":0,"Team_ID":3,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-01T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-07-12T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":null,"AssignedUser_ID":"","Completed_By":"","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43287},
"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":4554,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 5","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-06-09T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-06-10T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-09-28T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-09-29T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43288}],"Project_ID":15745,"ProjectType_ID":2,"ServiceStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","EmployerRef":"Sample Reference","Employer_ID":999999,"DocFolder":"","SalesStatus_ID":6,"SalesContact":"","ClientType_ID":2,"ChannelPartner_ID":4,"SelfInsuredMed":-1,"ProjectedRevenue":0,"NotificationDate":"2017-05-04T00:00:00","PHNumber":0,"Region_ID":0,"Segment_ID":0,"CCI_Required":0,"SSN_ID":1,"PlanYearStartDate":"2017-10-01T00:00:00","CardStatus_ID":1,"Cardcount":0,"PRIN":"","ConnectedClaims":0,"HSAFundingModel_ID":0,"CarryOverStatus_ID":2,"FundingDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","TermDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ProjectStatus_ID":2,"AccountMgr_ID":"A123456","SSO":0,"CustomWeb":0,"CustomWebURL":"","FSATakeover":0,"TOFileExpectedDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","NCC":-1,"Executed_Contract":null,"Performance_Guarantee":null,"Enrollment_Entered":null},"Project_ID":15745,"Task_ID":6200,"DKey":"","Description":"Sample Task 6","FirstTask":false,"PlannedDuration":1,"Team_ID":2,"EarlyStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","EarlyFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","LateFinishDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","PlannedStartDate":"2017-10-02T00:00:00","ActualStartDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00","ActualFinishDate":"2018-01-10T00:00:00","AssignedUser_ID":"A123456","Completed_By":"A123456","DurationEdit":null,"ID":43289}]
```

I can see what's happening. The Linq query is passing all tasks with the same project ID as the project, and then pulling the associated project for every task, and then passing the additional associated tasks for the project every time. What can I do in linq to make it not have all this additional data?

Here is the method I'm using:

```
public IEnumerable<ProjectTasks> GetProjectTasks(int id)
{
    IEnumerable<ProjectTasks> projecttasks = 
           (from x in db.ProjectTasks
            where x.Project_ID == id
            select x).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.ID);

    return projecttasks;
}
```

Comment: How do you "include the Project table in the entity data model"? Your method looks to be just returning a list of `ProjectTasks`, not `Projects`

Comment: Because in the entity model, the projecttasks table is connected to the project table by the foreign key "Project_ID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a view model that had only the fields you want, and then map the results to that and return an enumerable of that. Eg:

```
.Select(I=>new projectTaskViewmodel{
  Name = i.name,
  Date = i.date,
  Etc...
})
```

Comment: I see.  Visual Studio generates the Web API controller as passing the Entity Data Model so I just sort of assumed that's what should be passed.  Thank you.